# Break out from nested loop: SyntaxError: label not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, label

I have a very involved form that is requiring validation on all its elements so there already is a heavy burden in loading this page from PHP.

The customer wants validation for a grouping of fields so that when a grouping has something filled out for at least one row (x number of fields) that validation passes. Because of this I wrote a function that I want to break when it finds the first row, or subgrouping of inputs, so that it can go onto the next set of validation. If it can't find a suitable subgrouping within the group, it should alert().

In other iterations I tried to use return to bail out, but it went on to the alert anyway. So reading SO posts I'm trying a label to bail out as soon as the validation passes. Looking at these examples, it seems I'm doing what others suggest but I still get the SyntaxError: label not found.

Ok, according to the MDN docs it's not within the scope I think it is. I've moved the label up and down the hierarchy but getting it too close to the nested function makes it not useful for me here.

What would you do differently?

```
function checkRows(section) {
  agents = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];
  loop1:
  for (var key in agents) {

     innerElements = jQuery(":input[name^=" + section + "]." + agents[key]);

     if (innerElements.length > 0) {

       var checked = [];
       jQuery.each(innerElements, function(i, element) {
         console.log("element " + element + "; length=" + element.value.length);
         if (element.value.length > 0) {
           checked.push(element);
         };
         if (checked.length == i) {
           break loop1;
      }
       });     
     }    
  }
  alert("Please enter at least one set of values for " + section);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sam452/yj3myafq/3/

Comment: A `break` statement won't leave the function it's in. That `loop1` label is in a different function than the `break`.

Comment: What would I do differently : Firstly, I wouldn't be using a `for ... in` loop on an array, I wouldn't have all my variables as globals, and the last condition seems unneccessary ... etc

Comment: Also in general it's considered a Bad Idea to use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays. You can use the `.forEach()` function on the Array prototype, or a simple `for` loop with a numeric index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using $.each() jquery function

> "We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making
>   the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as
>   a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the
>   next iteration."

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Also you can call the checkrows() function inside the for loop